# How does convolving any arbitrary function wiht the impulse function returns the same arbitrary function?

Tags: convolution

When I was first introduced to convolution, I thought of it as an impulse with an amplitude of 1. This made it easier for me to comprehend the fact that convolving any arbitrary function x(t) with an impulse function returns back the function itself.

That is, if we have:
y(t)=x(t)*δ(t); where * is convolution

and we are interested in the value at t=t1, then
y(t1)=x(t1).1 ; where . is multiplication

this is because, δ(t1-T) is 0 everywhere except for t=t1, it is equal to 1.

However, I don't know how to reconcile with the fact that the impulse function doesn't have an amplitude of 1, but instead infinity. If so, then by the same logic:
y(t1)=x(t1).∞=∞

Can someone, point me to what I am missing?
Thank you

Comment: $\delta$ is not a function, it is a distribution.

Comment: We don't have $\delta(0)=1$, instead, we have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)\mathrm{d}x=1$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon}\delta(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int^{\infty}_{\varepsilon}\delta(x)\mathrm{d}x=0$. But working with distributions is slightly different from working with functions and you should be more careful.